# img does not respond

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help I am getting crazy about this
I am trying to set an image for a web app it should  be responsive but it is stretching and not re sizing when I change the browser  size
here is the code and the CSS

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="lista_de_categorias">
        @foreach (var categories in Model)

        {
            <li class="categorieslist">
                <a href="#">  

                    <div class="col-md-4 colum4">
                        <div class="categoriesdiv">
                            <h2 class="categoriesheading">Category Name</h2>
                        </div>

                        <img class="catImages" src="@categories.ImagePath" alt="images of different window blinds"/>

                    </div>

                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS for the `img` only

```
.catImages{

     display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width:100%;

    justify-content:center;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    height: auto;

}
```

But this is not working
I also tried `max-width:100%` but nothing

Comment: Do you mean the image is not resizing? It is working from my side though http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/yOYymR

Comment: @shark better put your work in a jsfiddle and showcase your problem. that way its better to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

looking to your classes `.col-md-4` and HTML structure I can see you are using [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap). so just use `.img-responsive` as stated in [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

Added `.container` to wrap `.row` as should be structured as well according to [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="lista_de_categorias">
      <li class="categorieslist">
        <a href="#">

          <div class="col-md-4 colum4">
            <div class="categoriesdiv">
              <h2 class="categoriesheading">Category Name</h2>
            </div>

            <img class="img-responsive catImages" src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" alt="images of different window blinds" />

          </div>

        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that the code you reply is working the way I want my code to work but I can not find the bug is making my code bad

Comment: I put that class form BS but still is stretching really bad

Comment: Well now I added the container class , apparently it does not work without that class. Images are not stretching or shinkring in one direction now but they are scaling at all